# Is it possible to prove the existence of an integer with given order while not finding the value itself?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The original question is here:

(a)Show that there is an integer a mod 249 whose order is 82.

[Hint: If h = ord_m(a), k = ord_n(a) and (m, n) = 1, then ord_mn(a) = [h, k]. ]

(b) Show that there is an integer b mod 249 whose order is 41.

(c) Show that there is no integer mod 249 whose order is 4.

(d) What are the possible orders of elements mod 249? Justify your answer.

In part (a), following the hint, it is natural to check that 249=83*3; phi(83)=82; 82=41*2

I'm hoping to find an existence of a value satisfying both

41=ord_83(a); 2=ord_3(a), and I'm stucked here since I cannot verify existence for one of it could also satisfy another. Yet with my programming knowledge, I have found some answers (e.g. 11) easily, though I'm pretty sure it is not the right way. Any helping hand?

Comment: Instead of order 41 mod 83 and 2 mod 3, why not go for order 82 mod 83, and order 1 mod 3?

Comment: It is okay but seemingly I still have to tackle the problem on solving two congruence equation simultaneously...

Comment: 3 and 83 are relatively prime, so the Chinese Remainder Theorem guarantees the existence of a simultaneous solution to the two congruences.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But I still can't see how CRT could deal with higher power...

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "deal with higher power". There exists $a$ such that if $x\equiv a\pmod{83}$ then $x$ has order 82 (mod 83), and there exists $b$ such that if $x\equiv b\pmod3$ then $x$ has order 1 (mod 3), and then CRT says there's an $x$ such that $x\equiv a\pmod{83}$ and $x\equiv b\pmod3$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint** Pick a primitive root $x$ mod $83$. Show that order of $x$ modulo 249 is a multiple of the order of $x$ mod $83$.

Then you can find powers $n, m$ such that the orders of $x^n$ and $x^m$ are $82$ respectively $41$. This solves $a,b$.

(c) Assume by contradiction this is true. Then $x^4 =1 \pmod{249}$. This means that 
$$x^4 =1 \pmod{83} \\
x^4=1 \pmod{3}$$

Prove that this implies that
$$x^2 =1 \pmod{83} \\
x^2=1 \pmod{3}$$
and use CRT.

Comment: I'm still not sure what CRT does to powered unknowns... It seems that $$x^2=1 \pmod{249} $$ can't help much

Comment: @orb If $x^2=1 \pmod{249}$ then the order is at most 2...But the order is 4...